# Asterisk and multitenant module for vtiger 6

Tags: vtiger

I am new to vtiger. I would like to know is there any modules available for Asterisk and multitenant. If so can you please give me the link. I saw some post saying it will be in future release.

Answer (score 0):

as per developers, setting PBX Manager back in action is planned in version 6.1
Meantime, you'll need to wait or create your custom module.

Answer (score 0):

check out http://www.vtigerexperts.com/vtiger-crm-6-1-demo/

PBX manager is available in 6.1. For multi-tenancy you have to customize.